# Do NFC tags have to be NDEF formated?

Tags: android, nfc

Do NFC tags have to be NDEF formated to read/write using a standard android app or a PC app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the tags don't need to contain data in NDEF format. You can use any format that you want.

The NFC API even provides several methods to read and write to tags in the native format. Here for example is the list of functions for Mifare Ultralight tags:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/tech/MifareUltralight.html

For those tag-types where no access API is provided by the NFC Api you can also directly send the commands to the tag using the transceive method.

Note that you loose quite a bit of abstraction if you go low-level. If you use NDEF the NFC-subsystem will abstract the differences between the different tag types for you.

Comment: So lets say I order Mifare Ultralight C tags from a supplier in China, could I program those tags straight out of box without being NDEF formatted with my Nexus S or my USB NFC Card Reader/Writer?

Comment: Yes. Just avoid type3 and type4 NFC-Tags unless you know how to program/format them.